# Jquery Transitions from some pages but not others

Tags: jquery, transition

On my home page I have my logo and menu centered and on all other pages they are in position at the top of the screen. I got this code to fade it in and out and keep the background from reloading.

What I like to know is how could I get it so that from the homepage it will fade into position but when moving to other pages it wont reload as it's already in position?

ie. Homepage > About/Contact page will fade in and out but from About > Contact these two items wont reload?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("body").css("display", "none");

$("body").fadeIn(3000);

$("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(3000, redirectPage);      
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}

});
```

Comment: Don't put the code on the other pages?

Comment: I've tried that, I need the code on those pages so the transition works when coming from the home page